# An infinite chain of finite set is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $Z$ be an infinite set of finite sets.

For all $X,Y\in Z$ we have $X\subseteq Y$ or $Y\subseteq X$.

I am trying to prove that $Z\sim\mathbb{N}$ where $\sim$ represents equivalence of sets.

I think I need to think of a function $f$ from $Z$ to $\mathbb{N}$ that is a bijection and that will prove this theorem, but I can't think of one. Hints?

Comment: What do you mean by $Z\sim\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are finite, distinct, and $X\subset Y$, then what can you say about their respective cardinalities?

Comment: @Leo163 I edited

Answer (score 3):

Prove that if $X\in Z$, and $|X|=n$, then there is no other $Y\in Z$ with $|Y|=n$.

This lets you define a natural injection from $Z$ into $\Bbb N$, and the fact that $Z$ is infinite should be enough to conclude the rest.

Comment: I'm surprised that you didn't mention that countable choice is required here.

Comment: I'm surprised that it's required here. :)

Comment: Oops, I was thinking about the union of $Z$, which is also countable, assuming countable AC.

Comment: Yeah, that's a whole other thing. :P it took me a moment when I read the question for the first time. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you explain little more? I didn't not quite catch it

Comment: @kickstart: Which part exactly?