# Can every set be expressed as the union of a chain of finite subsets?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Assume the axiom of choice. Let $X$ be an infinite set, can we always find a chain of finite subsets (using inclusion as the partial order) the whose union is the whole $X$?

This question is inspired by [this older question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605313/can-every-set-be-expressed-as-the-union-of-a-chain-of-sets-of-lesser-cardinality) which says there exists a chain of subsets of strictly smaller cardinaility whose union is whole $X$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can every set be expressed as the union of a chain of sets of lesser cardinality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605313/can-every-set-be-expressed-as-the-union-of-a-chain-of-sets-of-lesser-cardinality)

Comment: @AnneBauval In that other question the sets are not required to be ordered _by inclusion_...

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't think the answers of the earlier question solves my question. And I do not understand the reason why somebody has downvoted my question. Is it trivial? Is it ill-defined?

Comment: The other question allows sets of lesser cardinality, not finite.  Pretty sure with finite it'd be impossible for any uncountable set.   How would you have a union of the whole chain be uncountable and no union at a lesser step be countably infinite?

Comment: @Alan, I can't see what  you mean.

Comment: I agree with both of you, I made a mistake.

Comment: @Alan, [your intuition was right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573023/an-infinite-chain-of-finite-set-is-countably-infinite). Hence the answer to Doug Liu's question is: only if $X$ is countable.